# MySQL FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am trying to get how many partners are inserted by month in the last 12 months and I have this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(n.nid) AS expression FROM node n 
WHERE (FROM_UNIXTIME(created) >= '2014-07-01') 
AND (FROM_UNIXTIME(created) <= '2014-07-31') 
AND (n.type = 'partner') 
AND (n.status = 1)
```

So, I have one query for each month and th eproblem is that when I insert a partner in the first or last day of the month, It does NOT count, even that I using <= and >= operators.

Does anyone have any idea of what could be causing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What format is your `created` field stored in?  I wouldn't use `FROM_UNIXTIME` for date comparisons.

Comment: You don't need `FROM_UNIXTIME` in the `WHERE` clause. Try taking it out.

Comment: Your information in this question are insufficent to diagnose the problem completely. You've got to give us better the table definition statement with the data type of the `created` field, as Sam asked. Further we need the `INSERT` statements of both special days. I've got an explanation for the last day of month, that's easy enough: imagine FROM_UNIXTIME gives you `2014-07-31 19:58:30` That's  not less or equal than `2014-07-31`. The first day of month may be caused by time zone versus UTC time.

Comment: I am sorry guys. The created field is a timestamp.

Comment: Then I don't understand that your query works on inserts on the other days. `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(NOW()) as mytest;` gives `NULL` as result, because a MySQL timestamp is not an UNIX timestamp. You can use directly `WHERE (created >= '2014-07-01') AND ...` as superphonic said. To get around the problem I mentioned in my last comment you could use `(created < '2014-08-01')` instead. If you use a column instead of a calculated value MySQL can use an index if there is one.

Answer (score -1):

There's a function UNIX_TIMESTAMP that'll convert 0000-00-00 00:00:00 formatted value to linux timestamp integer.

You can use this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Am i right do you want to compare dates. If not please ignore this answer